# Syntax confusion regarding C++ while loops

Tags: c++

I recently started to learn C++ and I have a question regarding the syntax of an exercise given in our lecture about the accuracy when we declare different types of variables, in this case `float` and `double`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    // Accuracy test with float
    float eps_f = 1.0 ;
    while (float(1.0 + eps_f) != 1.0)
    eps_f /= 2.0 ;
    cout << "Resolving capacity float approximately: " << 2*eps_f << endl ;
    
     // Accuracy test with double
    double eps_d = 1.0 ;
    while (1.0 + eps_d != 1.0)
    eps_d /= 2.0 ;
    cout << "Resolving capacity double approximately : " << 2*eps_d << endl ;
}
```

So what I don't understand is what is the point of while here? What is happening?

Comment: This is why proper indentation and/or use of braces is so important for writing readable code. E.g.: the second loop is  `while (1.0 + eps_d != 1.0) { eps_d /= 2.0; }`

Comment: I rolled back the edit since the formatting is part of the issue here as answers have indicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, indentation does not affect the flow of a program, but it DOES affect the readability.

This can be better written as:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    // Accuracy test with float
    float eps_f = 1.0 ;
    while (float(1.0 + eps_f) != 1.0)
    {
        eps_f /= 2.0 ;
    }
    cout << "Resolving capacity float approximately: " << 2*eps_f << endl ;
    
     // Accuracy test with double
    double eps_d = 1.0 ;
    while (1.0 + eps_d != 1.0)
    {
        eps_d /= 2.0 ;
    } 
    cout << "Resolving capacity double approximately : " << 2*eps_d << endl ;
}
```

A while loop will operate on the next statement. If braces are used, it will treat the block enclosed in the braces as a statement. Otherwise, it will only use the next statement.

The following snippets are identical:

```cpp
while(1) 
{
    do_stuff();
}
 do_other_stuff();
```

```cpp
while(1) do_stuff(); do_other_stuff();
```

```cpp
while(1) 
do_stuff(); 
do_other_stuff();
```

Comment: While your example of the indented code is correct, writing `//end while` is a bad coding practice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was more using it as an attempt to demonstrate the block syntax. I have gone ahead and removed them.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation matters!

Here is the snippet re-written by adding sane indentation:

```
while (float(1.0 + eps_f) != 1.0)
    eps_f /= 2.0;
```

Now it is clear that while loop is executed until sum of `1.0` and `eps_f` becomes `1.0` - meaning that `eps_f` became so small that floating point math can not account for it.

Same change can be applied to the second `while` snippet with double.

Comment: "*Indentation matters!*" - only to human readers, not to the compiler

Comment: @RemyLebeau well, human readers matter too!